# Create list-group(boostrap) by php (Count contact in vcard file)

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Example:   If My Vcard  have a 10 contact.  Show 10 list group .

I try for loop  :   `for($i=0; $i<$vcard; $i++)`

In html:   `<a href="" class="list-group-item"> </a>`
In php:    I don't know how to create that

I have no idea to do right now.  Can you help me?

in html    
in php    I dont know how to create that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$vcard` is an array you could do

```
foreach($vcard as $contact) {
  // do something with the data of $contact
}
```

[PHP manuael foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

But you can also stay with your `for`-loop

```
for($i=0; $i < count($vcard); $i++) {
  // do something with data of $vcard[$i]
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. If it help's you please accept the answer to show other users that this was a working solution for you.